# Manjaro - broadcom-wl not working

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, manjaro

When I run `lspci -vnn -d 14e4:` I get:

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619]
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 10
        Memory at df400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32K]
        Memory at df200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=2M]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel modules: bcma
```

I tried `yaourt -S broadcom-wl` (which is supposed to be the alternative driver for this card) and rebooted but there is still no option for wifi. I have also installed `broadcom-wl-dkms`, `b43-firmware`, `b43-firmware-classic` (Which manjaro seems to come with by default).

It is important to note that this wireless card worked with Ubuntu when I enabled the wireless driver for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it's because `yaourt` gave me the wrong version for my kernel. I used `pacman -S broadcom-wl` and chose the package with the correct prefix (I have kernel 4.19 so I chose `linux419-broadcom-wl`